# What is the difference between GUID and ID in a .vsct file in Visual Studio extension programming?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

e.g. Consider the following code:

```
<Group guid="guidFirstCommandCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
</Group>

<Group guid="guidSecondCommandCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
</Group>
```

Here, why do we need to define both GUID and ID? id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS" refers to Tools menu in Visual Studio. What is the use of guid="guidSHLMainMenu"?

Also consider the following code:

```
  <Button guid="guidSecondCommandCmdSet" id="cmdidSecondCommand" priority="2" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidSecondCommandCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup"/>
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic2"/>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>XXX Command</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
```

I understand that the button has the id called "cmdidSecondCommand", but where would the GUID of the button be used? We are already defining the Parent container of the button in the next element.

Comment: The guid is replaced by the compiler by a Globally Unique ID.  It ensures that your command set can never collide with another one that was created by a programmer that you don't know.

Comment: If the GUID is globally unique, why is an additional ID required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `GUID` is as the name implies a [globally unique identifier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) in the form of `{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}`. An `ID` is a key (or identifier); which is used like a constant allowing to give descriptive names to numeric values.

Since the values behind an `ID` are not unique over all command sets (or image-strips), the `GUID` is used to put them into context... a combination of a guid and a numeric value is used to uniquely identify groups, menus, toolbars, buttons, images etc...

In the given example `MyMenuGroup` and `IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS` could potentially have the same mumeric value, but the guids `guidSecondCommandCmdSet`and `guidSHLMainMenu` put them into context...

```
<Group guid="guidSecondCommandCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
</Group>
```

You need the `GUID` and the `ID` when you want to register Execute- and QueryStatus handlers for controls in your code, set an icon for a button, set elements into relation; for instance adding a group to a toolbar, or menu and so on...

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful.